# Postfix Autorespond - "recipient address rejected"

Tags: email, postfix, auto-reply

I have an issue with postfix.

If I set up an autorepsonder (I use a postgresql db, so I insert `mailbox#mydomain@autoreply.mydomain.net` into alias table; of course this domain is listed into postfix's `transport` file) this will work only for local domains.

If I try to send mail from external domains, I receive back `Relay access denied;` 
As last tentative, if I send in a "conventional way" mail to same address that is "denied" with autorespond operation, I'm able to send it without any problem.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was into `main.cf` postfix's configuration file: `$mynetworks` does not contain server ip (only localhost: `127.0.0.1`) and, so, message was rejected.
By adding my server ip address, all works like a charm.